# cx_freeze'd PySide application stylesheet does not apply

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyside, cx-freeze

I have encountered a strange issue when using `cx_Freeze` to make an executable. When running a script directly (i.e. `python main.py`) the app behaves as expected. After packing with `cx_Freeze` application stylesheet does not get applied. Core logic works, but the looks are default. Although, if I set stylesheet on a widget directly it does get applied, so it's not missing stylesheet engine.

#### Dev Box

```
OS:        Windows 7, 64 bit  
Python:    3.3.2, 32 bit  
PySide:    1.2.1  
Qt:        4.8.4  
cx_Freeze: 4.3.2
```

#### Target box

OS: Windows 8.1, 64 bit
Input: 10 point touchscreen

#### Screenshots

In order to visualize the problem I'm providing sample screenshots:

- How it looks normally:

  [image]
- How it looks packed:

  [image]

The left button has stylesheet applied directly and it does not change fonts

#### Errors:

If I run frozen application (with default script) on target box, it spits out following error message:

```
QAccessibleWidget::rect: This implementation does not support subelements! (ID 2 unknown for MenuBar)
```

I have tried using default `cx_Freeze` script, followed some answers here and written my own to include `atexit` and `PySide.QtCore`, but with no apparent luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is your stylesheet applied? Can you create a small runnable example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Fenikso using `QApplication::setStyleSheet()` method. I'll try to create a minimum working example and will update my question with a gist

Comment: Also does it fail on your dev box? Because I do not have Windows 8.